# Calculate a column from others and write result in the table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a leaderboard for a game. The game consists of differents games tagged with their own ID. The 'participations' table in the MySQL db looks like this:

```
| participation_id | user_id | score1 | score2 | score3 | total |
| 1                | 23      | 78     | 12     | 98     |       |
| 2                | 31      | 68     | 45     | 95     |       |
| 3                | 23      | 98     | 23     | 100    |       |
```

All score go from 0 to 100 just for your information.
I want to fill the total column with `score1+score2+score3` for each participation and put `NULL` or `0` if another participation run by the same user had a better total score.
I'm kind of a beginner when it come to MySQL scripting so I'm asking you, especially for the second part of the script :/

**Note concerning the total score:** I don't calculate the total score when inserting the row as score values need to be normalised to go from 0 to 100.

**EDIT:** As writing to the DB would create redundancy and is not required in my case, I update my question: How do I filter these results to only keep the best score for each user?

```
| user_id | total |
| 1       | 98    |
| 2       | 45    |
| 1       | 12    |
| 2       | 69    |
| 1       | 54    |
```

**EDIT2:** The easiest solution was to use `GROUP BY` like this:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(total) AS score
FROM table_name
GROUP BY score
```

Thanks for your recommendations!

Comment: I would suggest against conditionally populating the total column based on a users other totals.  In fact, I would recommend against adding a total column altogether... you can do the totaling and conditional selection inside queries, instead of within the table itself.

Answer (score 3):

Why bother with the total, when you can do something like this?

```
SELECT
   user_id,
   MAX(score_1 + score_2 + score_3)
FROM
   scores
GROUP BY
   user_id
```

This would give you each users best total score. If you're looking to do something more complex then just ask, but adding the total column violates normal form ( So does having score_1, score_2, score_3 btw).

A better design might be:

```
participation_id  user_id  score_id  score
1                 23       1         78
1                 23       2         12
1                 23       3         98
2                 31       1         68
...
```

Comment: I know I can calculate the total through a query. The reason why I wanted to store the value in a column or in another table (the important thing being that the value is stored somewhere, not in the DB RAM) is that the participation table will have thousands of rows and I can't afford to recalculate the total value each time a user presses F5 and create a complex query. Instead I'd like to force the calculation only every 5-10 minutes. Between calculations the php file will only retrieve the 'outdated' values for total. Don't know if my explanation is clear lol

Comment: I think your fears are somewhat unfounded. The added overhead of calculating the MAX() is negligible compared to your proposed solution of having a pre-populated field with the total. Either way you will have to locate the specific row amongst the thousands. Adding 3 columns adds very little overhead to that. If you index properly this shouldn't be a big issue. Normal Form should be your goal, only denormalize if absolutely necessary. In this case  it isn't necessary.

Comment: Alright in that case, the inserting of the total value is not a problem anymore. I managed to create the query. Now What I need is to filter the results to only keep the best participation for each user. I'm going to update the main topic to reflect this.